# Push JSON object in Nested Array in Javascript

Tags: json, node.js, sequelize.js

I am a newcomer in node and JSON and can't able to get a desired JSON response. I want a response to be sent to app in an organized grouped manner. I have tried in several ways to come to a logic how to go into the array of arrays & Json objects but failed. Please help.
My code is as follows:

```
    models.sequelize.query("SELECT product_details.item_name, product_details.item_desc, product_details.current_price, store_details.store_name, store_details.google_place_id, store_details.store_address, offer_recs.offer_id, offer_recs.offer, offer_recs.createdAt FROM `offer_recs` LEFT OUTER JOIN scan_recs ON scan_recs.scan_id = offer_recs.scan_id LEFT OUTER JOIN store_details ON store_details.store_id = offer_recs.store_id LEFT OUTER JOIN product_details ON product_details.prod_id = scan_recs.prod_id LEFT OUTER JOIN buyer_acct_details ON buyer_acct_details.buyer_id = scan_recs.buyer_id WHERE buyer_acct_details.buyer_id="+req.user.buyer_id+" ORDER BY store_details.store_name ASC, product_details.item_name ASC", { type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
    .then(offers=>{
        var store_name = '', tmp_store_name = '', offer_history = [], allOffers = [], i = 0, j=0;
        offers.forEach(offer=>{
            if (offer.store_name != null) {
                if (i==0) {
                    tmp_store_name = offer.store_name;
                    store_name = offer.store_name;
                    offer_history.push({item_name: offer.item_name, store_name: offer.store_name});
                    allOffers.push({store_name: store_name, offers: offer_history});
                } else {
                    if (i>0 && offer.store_name == tmp_store_name) {
                        offer_history.push({item_name: offer.item_name, store_name: offer.store_name});
                    } else {
                        if (i>0 && store_name[i]!=store_name[i-1]) {
                            allOffers.push({store_name: store_name[i-1], offers: offer_history})
                            offer_history=[];
                            store_name[i] = offer.store_name;
                            //offer_history.push({item_name: offer.item_name, item_desc: offer.item_desc, store_name: offer.store_name});
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        })
        res.status(200).send({success: true, msg: "Successfully fetched offers", Result: allOffers});
    });
```

I want a JSON response in the following manner:

```
Result: 
[
{
store_name: "Citimart",
offers:[
                {
                    "item_name": "Television",
                    "item_desc": "LED Television",
                    "current_price": "24999.0000",
                    "store_name": "Citimart",
                    "google_place_id": "ChIJ8Xdmiwh3AjoRvzKnSWdFwbU",
                    "store_address": "3A, Humayan Place Lighthouse Building, New Market Area, Dharmatala, Taltala, Kolkata, West Bengal 700087, India",
                    "offer": "18500.0000",
                    "createdAt": "2018-07-20T17:03:20.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "item_name": "Toaster",
                    "item_desc": "Maharaja Toaster",
                    "current_price": "2999.0000",
                    "store_name": "Citimart",
                    "google_place_id": "ChIJ8Xdmiwh3AjoRvzKnSWdFwbU",
                    "store_address": "3A, Humayan Place Lighthouse Building, New Market Area, Dharmatala, Taltala, Kolkata, West Bengal 700087, India",
                    "offer": "2500.0000",
                    "createdAt": "2018-07-21T06:48:11.000Z"
                }
            ]
},
 {           store_name: "Walmart Delhi",
offers: [
        {
                    "item_name": "Mobile",
                    "item_desc": "Samsung Smartphone J7",
                    "current_price": "11999.0000",
                    "store_name": "Walmart Delhi",
                    "google_place_id": "ChIJMcg5Nor8DDkR6hrTdF7Cido",
                    "store_address": "87, GT Road, New Seelampur, New Seelampur I, Shahdara, Delhi, 110053, India",
                    "offer": "1500.0000",
                    "createdAt": "2018-07-20T17:03:20.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "item_name": "Television",
                    "item_desc": "LED Television",
                    "current_price": "24999.0000",
                    "store_name": "Walmart Delhi",
                    "google_place_id": "ChIJMcg5Nor8DDkR6hrTdF7Cido",
                    "store_address": "87, GT Road, New Seelampur, New Seelampur I, Shahdara, Delhi, 110053, India",
                    "offer": "15000.0000",
                    "createdAt": "2018-07-20T17:04:05.000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add your model code here

Comment: what output do you currently get instead? What does the source data look like? Very hard for us to amend your code without knowing what data we are working with. BTW your stated desired output is not valid JSON. All the property names must have double-quotes around them, and you can't prepend the string "Result:" to the array declaration. Also there are some closing brackets missing from your example.

Comment: Please close this matter. I have solved it on my own.